# Android : ViewPager in ScrollView not scrolling if item exceed in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_first_time_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.vikas.donna.ui.activities.FirstTimeProfileActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="284dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_fill_gradient_primary_white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_first_time_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_first_time_profile"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/userpic" />

            <com.vikas.donna.customcomponents.customfonts.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                style="@style/font_work_sans_medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/iv_profile_image"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Vikas Rohilla"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.vikas.donna.customcomponents.customfonts.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_tag_line"
                style="@style/font_work_sans_medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_profile_name"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:alpha="0.80"
                android:text="I am software engineer"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="11sp" />


            <com.vikas.donna.customcomponents.customfonts.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/customTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_tag_line"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_fill_primary_trans"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/red_dot"
                android:drawablePadding="9dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="24dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Busy in meeting till 5.00 pm"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

If fragment in view pager contains long list then it won't scroll. Even after Adding Scrollview it show the still screen.
If add Scrollview in ViewPager child fragment instead of activity then it scroll only the fragment part not above part. 
What should I do now

Comment: You can not scroll both side with ViewPager and Scrollview. It causes performance issue and its a bad practice too. Try to use nested scrollview or try to handle it manually.

Comment: put your viewpager inside NestedScrollView

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Where have you reached with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener;

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
    setFadingEdgeLength(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
            && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

// Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction
class YScrollDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}



public class NestingViewPager extends ViewPager {

public NestingViewPager(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NestingViewPager(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    if (v != this && v instanceof ViewPager) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am able to see, you have put a horizontal `ViewPager` inside a vertical `ScrollView` which, in and of itself, is a problematic arrangement: Is a gesture meant to scroll the `ViewPager` or the `ScrollView`? The `ListView` in the `ViewPager`'s `Fragment` compounds the problem further: when a user touches the list, should the focus be on the `ListView` or the `ScrollView`?

You can try one of the following approaches:

**1.** Try using a `RecyclerView` and a `NestedScrollView` instead of a `ListView` and a `ScrollView`.

**2.** Alternatively, define an `interface` that locks focus on the `ListView` when it is touched (and vice-versa):

```
public interface FocusLock {
    void lock();
    void unlock();
}
```

Then create a custom `ListView` and override its `dispatchTouchEvent()` method as follows:

```
public class NestedListView extends ListView{

    private FocusLock mCallbackControl;

    public void setCallback(FocusLock callbackControl) {
        this.mCallbackControl = callbackControl;
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mCallbackControl.lock();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mCallbackControl.unlock();
                break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

In your `Fragment`, you must initialize the `ListView` as follows:

```
NestedListView mNestedListView = findViewById(R.id.list);
mNestedListView.setCallback(new FocusLock() {

                @Override
                public void lock() {
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void unlock() {
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                }
            });
```

Hope this makes sense.

Try this. One of these approaches should work.